# What is the index route in UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make a link to the home or index route using Anuglar UI-Router. For example, on a local server, this would just be `localhost:8000`. I've tried `<a ui-sref="#">Home</a>` and `<a ui-sref="/">Home</a>`, but the link renders as plain text with no blue highlight, and when clicked on, the console reports:

```
 Could not resolve '#' from state ''
```

Can this be achieved without making an extra route in `$stateProvider`, and if not, what would the proper route for the `index.html` page be like?

Comment: read the docs ... you use the state name not the url

Comment: @charlietfl I know, but it's pointing to `index.html`, why define a named route? It should be default.

Comment: Well if it's not a defined route then you just use href as it has nothing to do with router. Not entirely clear what you are trying to do

Comment: you *should* define a route, even if it is the index route.  `$stateProvider.state('index', {url: '/', views: {...}, template: 'layout.html'})`  something like that.  and use `a ui-sref='index'>Home</a>`  This will render `<a href='/'>Home</a>`.  Since this is the end result you want, that is the way you go about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ui-sref` you need to mention the **state name** not the relative url path.

For example if you want to link to home page then you could do either of the below:

**1. Using ui-sref:**

```
<a ui-sref="home-page">Home</a>
```

Here **home-page** is the state name given to path "/" in your router:

```
$stateProvider.state('home-page', {
    url: "/", // using home-page in ui-sref will redirect to this url
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller:"HomeController"
});
```

**2. Using href:**

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

***Note:*** `ui-sref` will come in handly when state has **search queries** in url, read about [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) to know more.